# ASP.Net MVC RDLC Mail Concept is not Working for me on live server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rdlc

It is showing Report Viewer but On live server Only(Smarterasp.net server)Mail Concept is not working. Please help me to fixed this problem, I did not published that RDLC and I did not Change that RDLC into Embedded Content, Just I Uploaded that RDLC Folder

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to be more specific on your issue. Is there any error message? Have you contacted their support team to take a look on your issue?